# Unit Test ASP.Net View Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

In Razor, I can define a function within a view like this:

```
@functions{
    internal string Foo(string text)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Is it possible to unit test such a function?  If so, how?

Comment: Generally speaking, you won't.  If the string function is elaborate, you can put it in an outboard library, and test it there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sure, but that minimizes what one can sensibly do with in-view functions.

Comment: I don't see how, unless you're referring to local state in your `Foo` function, which is going to make it maddeningly difficult to unit test. If you put your functions in a static class and avoid side-effects, passing in the needed parameters only, you can scale up as much as you want, and the functions will be easily testable in the usual way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to unit test such a function?

No. But you have this function call a real function that could be unit tested.